# Drop-down menu is empty when testing in Cucumber (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, simple-form

I'm using Cucumber to do some testing for my Rails app, and all has gone well until I reached the point where I have to choose an option from a drop-down menu. (A selector made with the `simple_form` gem.) I have the `selenium-webdriver` gem installed.

This menu works in real-life testing (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), but when I run the Cucumber tests, the menu is empty. I have `@javascript` enabled for the scenario and I see it running through Firefox. It can find the menu, and when it "clicks" on it, the list is empty, so the test fails (because it needs to select an indicated option -- which isn't there). Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the code in cucumber (step definition)

```
#...
find('#user_device_device_id').click
select('<some menu option>', :from => 'user_device_device_id' )
#...
```

And this is the HAML code for the dropdown in new.html:

```
= simple_form_for [:manage, @user_device], :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' } do |f|
  = f.select(:device_id, Device.all.collect{ |d| [d.get_name, d.id, {'data-connectiontype' => d.connection_type}] }, :required => true)
```

Source code of the selector in HTML (from Firefox -- not during Cucumber test):

```
<select id="user_device_device_id" name="user_device[device_id]">
  <option value="1" data-connectiontype="abc">Device 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-connectiontype="defg">Device 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the minimum amount of code that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: @orde Done. Hope that's enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the problem. The database used in testing is always empty at start, so none of my devices actually existed in testing. The fix was just to call `Device.create!` with the necessary parameters in one of the steps before I go to the form page. Worked perfectly.